# Seleccionar fecha y saber el día de la semana que seleccionó

Tags: javascript, php, html, funciones

Tengo el siguiente código:

Lo que necesito hacer es que al momento en que el usuario seleccione una fecha automáticamente me de el día de la semana de la fecha que seleccionó con la función de PHP que se observa, si lo hace pero el detalle es que es hasta que le doy clic en el botón solicitar.. Esto es por medio de PHP:

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
  <label>FECHA: </label>
  <input type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha" required>
</div>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['fecha'])){
  function saber_dia($nombredia) {
    $dias = array('Domingo','Lunes','Martes','Miércoles','Jueves','Viernes','Sabado');
    $fecha = $dias[date('N', strtotime($nombredia))];
    echo $fecha;
  }
  // ejecutamos la función pasándole la fecha que queremos
  $num_dia = saber_dia($_POST['fecha']);
  
  switch ($num_dia) {
    case 0:
      if ($row_h['mat'] == 1) {
        $entrada = $row_h['e11'];
        $salida = $row_h['s11'];
      }
      if ($row_h['ves'] == 1) {
        $entrada = $row_h['e11'];
        $salida = $row_h['s11'];
      }
      break;
    case 1:
      if ($row_h['mat'] == 1) {
        $entrada = $row_h['e11'];
        $salida = $row_h['s11'];
      }
      if ($row_h['ves'] == 1) {
        $entrada = $row_h['e11'];
        $salida = $row_h['s11'];
      }
      break;
    case 2:
      if ($row_h['mat'] == 1) {
        $entrada = $row_h['e11'];
        $salida = $row_h['s11'];
      }
      if ($row_h['ves'] == 1) {
        $entrada = $row_h['e11'];
        $salida = $row_h['s11'];
      }
      break;
    case 3:
      if ($row_h['mat'] == 1) {
        $entrada = $row_h['e11'];
        $salida = $row_h['s11'];
      }
      if ($row_h['ves'] == 1) {
        $entrada = $row_h['e11'];
        $salida = $row_h['s11'];
      }
      break;
    case 4:
      if ($row_h['mat'] == 1) {
        $entrada = $row_h['e11'];
        $salida = $row_h['s11'];
      }
      if ($row_h['ves'] == 1) {
        $entrada = $row_h['e11'];
        $salida = $row_h['s11'];
      }
      break;
    case 5:
      if ($row_h['mat'] == 1) {
        $entrada = $row_h['e11'];
        $salida = $row_h['s11'];
      }
      if ($row_h['ves'] == 1) {
        $entrada = $row_h['e11'];
        $salida = $row_h['s11'];
      }
      break;
    case 6:
      if ($row_h['mat'] == 1) {
        $entrada = $row_h['e11'];
        $salida = $row_h['s11'];
      }
      if ($row_h['ves'] == 1) {
        $entrada = $row_h['e11'];
        $salida = $row_h['s11'];
      }
      break;
    default:
      echo "";
      break;
  }
} 
?>

  <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name="enviar" value="Solicitar">
```

También lo he intentado por medio de JAVASCRIPT con está función:
Explico un poco, mi problema es que ya me da el día pero a la hora de extraer el resultado en una variable de PHP es lo que no sé, para iniciar a hacer comparaciones en el `switch`

```js
var dias = ["Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado", "Domingo"];

function diaSemana() {
  var x = document.getElementById("fecha");
  alert("Día: " + dias[x.valueAsDate.getDay()]);
}
```

```html
<input type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha" required onchange="diaSemana();">
```

Muchas gracias por su atención espero que me logren entender y ayudar...

Comment: Sí deseas obtener los datos de PHP , sin presionar el botón . se podría realizar haciendo uso de Ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que entiendo es que no sabes como pasar el día a php por medio de una variable, Si es así puedes crear un input oculto que tenga como valor el dia.

```js
let dias = ["Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado","Domingo"];

  function diaSemana() {
   var x = document.getElementById("fecha");
      let date = new Date(x.value);
      let hidden = document.getElementById('day_of_week');
      hidden.value = dias[date.getDay()];
   console.log(hidden.value);
  }
```

```html
<input type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha" required onchange="diaSemana();">
<input type="hidden" name="day_of_week" id="day_of_week"/>
```

En PHP puedes obtener el día de la semana con

```
<?php
  $_GET['day_of_week'] // o
  $_POST['day_of_week'] // Según el método que uses en el formulario
<?
```

Puedes hacerlo con PHP pero tendrías que utilizar ajax.

Answer (score 0):

La función `saber_dia` tiene un error. En lugar de hace `echo $fecha;` usa `return $fecha;`

Un saludo

Comment: Eso parece ser la respuesta, según yo lo veo. Te felicito para el buen ojo, @loc-nar.

Comment: Y ten un poco más autoestima, cuando tienes razón, Si escribes "Creo que" hay gente que ni comprueban si tuviste razon y te tratan como si no supieras que haces ;)